# What is a West Coast (U.S.) accent?

Tags: american-english, accent

I've seen [references](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/standard-american-english/1889#1889) to the American Midwest as being the home of the least accented form of American English.  I always think of the Northern Midwest as having an accent that I associate with Canadians and that the West Coast (California, Oregon, Washington) is the closest to "Standard American English."

What are the features of the "West Coast" accent (if any)?

Comment: SNL pretty much nailed it with ["The Californians"](http://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/the-californians/n13474?snl=1).  "Steyewart, eywhadaryewdoinhere?"  Plus you get to watch Bill Hader almost lose it in the middle of the skit.  :)

Comment: [“General American doesn’t exist. He was demoted to private or sergeant a long, long time ago.”](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/is-there-a-place-in-america-where-people-speak-without-accents)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Atlas of North American English has a rather broad definition of the West. Its primary characteristics are:

- The merger of words sounding like *cot* and *caught* (they're pronounced the same)
- The fronting of /uw/, as in *boot* but not /ow/, as in *boat*
- No monophthongization of /ay/, as in *ride*

So, these features more or less distinguish the West from its neighboring dialects, but don't do much to specifically define the West. There are also some finer grained distinctions within the West that would make a broad and complete definition impossible. For example

- Apparently *fill* and *feel* are pronounced the same in Salt Lake City, per [this stupid criminal story](http://www.ksl.com/?nid=148&sid=3058039).
- There is a distinct vowel shift occurring in Northern California ([academic description](http://www.stanford.edu/~eckert/vowels.html)) some features were stereotyped in [the Shoes video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCF3ywukQYA).

Comment: I'm fascinated that we're having a vowel shift here -- I don't recognize the changes she's listed (except maybe for look becoming luck), but I defer to the expert.  I'll have to listen more closely.

Comment: It's so funny to read about an accent I have: "merger of 'cot' and 'caught'" -- sounds funny to have it pointed out; from my POV with the accent in question, they have always been the same! It's hard to imagine how they would be differentiated?

Comment: "Baby caught. As new. Must sell today": seen in classifieds.

Comment: In Southern California, "-ing" and "-ink" are pronounced "-eeng" and "-eenk"; that is, /ɪ/ becomes /i/ before /ŋ/.

Answer (score 1):

West coast accent can also include the word "aunt" being pronounced "ant" rather than "aw-nt"

Some word are used more than others like "like" and the style is considered more informal than the East Coast, Midwest, or South.

[West Coasters often say "soda"](http://www.popvssoda.com/) when others say "pop" and in parts of the South every soft drink is a "Coke."

Comment: I've found "pop" to be a Midwest thing - bubbly beverages are almost uniformly "soda" in California.

Comment: Another word: west coasters (Arizonans?) say pajamas (pa-JAM-uhs as in bread and jam vs. puh-JAW-muhs as in jawbone).

Comment: The word *"aunt"* is pronounced as *"ant"* everywhere in the U.S. except a few enclaves on the East Coast (most notably New England).

Answer (score 1):

I grew up on the West Coast but went to college on the gulf coast.  One thing I notice about westcoasters, we don't articulate our "t" very well. For instance, people in Washington say "Ren'in", not "Renton".  "Didn", not "did not".  Also, it's Portlund, Orgun, not Portland, Oreeygone.  Like the beautiful city of Nawlins, LA, we should all try to pronounce the names of places like the locals do.

Comment: Pronouncing foreign cities “like the locals do” rather than in one’s native accent sounds rather precious (read: pretentious).  Do you say *Madrid, Paris, München* as the locals do? I highly doubt it. Then why discard your native accent for singular words? *Oregon* in the Midwest is certainly not homophonic with *organ*, despite that being the designated foreign pronunciation. So what?

Comment: I have always strived to pronounce all foreign words, not only place names, as they are, by native speakers, as closely as possible. Was I doing the wrong thing?

Comment: @Kris: it depends on the actual place name. If you say *Missoura* and don't say *Cincinnata*, or if you only drop the r in *New Yawk* and not in other words, I suspect you're betraying the fact that you're pandering to the locals (half of whom pronounce it *Missouri* anyway). On the other hand, if you say *Ore-ih-gun* instead of *Ore-ee-gone*, or *Illi-noy* instead of *Illi-noise*, the locals will definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the school program called "Plato", but people have asked for clarification, because they can't tell if i'm saying "Plato" or "Play-doh", which led me to be conscious of the fact that people living in the American Northwest don't strongly pronunciate the letter "t", so for example, "Seattle" sounds more like "Sea-addle".

Answer (score -2):

I notice most urban WC people pronounce /ar/ as //or/ as in yard they say yord.  Or yeah is yeeah. Also ir is pronounced ur is in girl is gurl. Also tion is shun.

Comment: Are there any accents of English that don't pronounce *girl* to rhyme with *curl*? That don't pronounce *-tion* as *shun*? These aren't features of the West Coast accent; they're features of nearly every English dialect.